# How can I use a sprite sheet in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Hi I have already this code:

```
var refreshIntervalId;
var myImages = [
    "walking1.jpg",
    "walking2.jpg",
    "walking3.jpg",
    "walking4.jpg",
    "walking5.jpg",

];
var counter = 0;  


function switchImage() {
    $('#myImage').attr('src', myImages[counter]);
    counter += 1;

    if (counter == Number($("#counter").val())) {
        counter = 0;
        clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);



    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#animationBtn").click(function(){
        refreshIntervalId = setInterval(switchImage, 50);
    }); 
});
```

But now I want instead of an image to play an spritesheet, is this possible? or do I have to change the whole code, yes? can someone help me with that?

Comment: You may want to look into how [jqueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller) does its icons.  That's effectively a use of a sprite sheet.

Comment: Yes, displaying different sections of a sprite sheet is very different from displaying different images. It is indeed possible, try it.

Comment: Look I have made an animation in Adobe flash and came out with all those images so I thought that it would be easier to collect them in a sprite sheet but do you guys know how I can use my animation made in adobe flash at the same way I could change the images in my question above? so I don't want to get one image shown but the whole animation has to be shown if I choose 1 for example

Answer (score 3):

A spritesheet is a sheet is basically an image file with a bunch of images, representing one (or several) animation sequence.

[**For example**](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/):

```
#nav li a {background-image:url('../img/image_nav.gif')}
#nav li a.item1 {background-position:0px 0px}
#nav li a:hover.item1 {background-position:0px -72px}
#nav li a.item2 {background-position:0px -143px;}
#nav li a:hover.item2 {background-position:0px -215px;}
```

Loading the image once and by changing the **`background-position`** displaying the other images in spritesheet.

Check this [**spritecow**](http://www.spritecow.com/), an online tool(my favorite) to get the `background-position` of individual images in the spritesheet.

Comment: +1 - That is a neat tool! :) It can be at times be bothersome to fire up a graphics program just for pixel offsets and dimensions.

Comment: @user1671639 thanks for your reply, if I use the tool I get this code: .sprite {
 background: url('imgs/walkingman.png') no-repeat 0 0;
 background-size: 1684px 801px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
} how can I use this in combination with my code so it has the same function

Comment: @user2852398 As I mentioned in example, add the css to respective individual elements.

Comment: @user1671639 actually I don't get it this is what I want Look I have made an animation in Adobe flash and came out with all those images so I thought that it would be easier to collect them in a sprite sheet but do you guys know how I can use my animation made in adobe flash at the same way I could change the images in my question above? so I don't want to get one image shown but the whole animation has to be shown if I choose 1 for example

Comment: @user2852398 I couldn't get.  But I understood that animation is your priority.  Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/ designed by Simurai

Comment: @user1671639 I get the whole spritesheet on my page but I don't get the animation part but even if I had the animated part, the thing I want to accoplish is that the annimation has to start if I click on it or like my exapmle were it stops at the number it needs to stop

Comment: @user2852398 possible to setup a fiddle?

Comment: @user1671639 http://jsfiddle.net/u6xM9/ I dont have the image online but this is the code

Comment: @user2852398 without your image it is difficult to check this.  Try to host here http://postimage.org/

Comment: and it works but now I want the animation to stop at the last picture

Comment: and if I make an other animation I want it to play the first and the second and end at the second

Comment: @user2852398 To stop at last picture replace `infinite` with `1` like   `-webkit-animation: play .8s steps(10) 1;`

Comment: @user1671639 http://jsfiddle.net/EpPZQ/3/ this one is working I don't know why the other one isn't but this is what needs to be done but than each image has to be an sprite sheet is this possible?

Comment: @user1671639 can you explain how I can get the same effect as this http://jsfiddle.net/EpPZQ/3/ but with the code you gave me?

Comment: @user2852398 First collect the list of images and make it as sprite.  Take some reference in net, you misunderstood the concept  of sprite sheet.

Comment: @user1671639 so what your saying is that I rather don't work with sprite sheets? because the only thing I actually want to accoplish is to play different sprite sheets one after another

Comment: @user1671639 http://jsfiddle.net/CGmCe/4094/ this is how you can play a second animation but I want the second animation at the same place as the first and that the user can decide if only the first animation to play or the first and the second